# Mysql Storing a variable with the result of an SELECT CASE

Tags: mysql, variables, select, case, store

im learning how to use the SELECT CASE but i don't understand very well, here is the code:

```
SET @vgls=1;
SET @lgls=1;


SET @st=SELECT CASE 
WHEN @vgls=@lgls THEN "emp"
WHEN @vgls>@lgls THEN "loc"
WHEN @vgls<@lgls THEN "vis" END;

SELECT @st;
```

It gives me the following error:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CASE 
WHEN @vgls=@lgls THEN "emp"
WHEN @vgls>@lgls THEN "loc"
WHEN @vg' at line 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

```
SELECT
...
INTO var_name [, var_name]]
```

instead of `set` to assign the result of a SELECT to a variable. So this should do it:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN @vgls=@lgls THEN "emp"
WHEN @vgls>@lgls THEN "loc"
WHEN @vgls<@lgls THEN "vis" END
INTO @st;
```