# Mysql: Set variable using a case from a variable

Tags: mysql

What I have is a bit column `NonMileage` and based on that bit column i want to make a variable that I can use inside of a where clause.

this is a two part question:

1. How do you case a variable? The code below does not case the
   @NoMileageListing
2. And then I have it setting @MileListingClause as a string, can I
   just use @MileListingClause like where @MileListingClause?

.

```
SET @NoMileageListing = (SELECT NonMileage FROM tbldealerships);
SELECT 
    @NoMileageListing CASE @NoMileageListing when 1 then 
        SET @MileListingClause = 'tblcargarage.miles >= 0' else 
        SET @MileListingClause = 'tblcargarage.miles != 0' end case;
```

here's the answer

```
SET @NoMileageListing = (SELECT NonMileage FROM tbldealerships);

SELECT CASE @NoMileageListing
          WHEN 1 THEN 'tblcargarage.miles >= 0'
          ELSE 'tblcargarage.miles != 0'
       END
  INTO @NoMileWhereClause;
  select @NoMileWhereClause;
```

found here:
[Mysql Storing a variable with the result of an SELECT CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871014/mysql-storing-a-variable-with-the-result-of-an-select-case)

Comment: What type of `@NoMileageListing`? Is it temporary table? Because `(SELECT NonMileage FROM tbldealerships)` give you result set of `NonMileage`.

Comment: @bitoshi.n I'm not sure what you mean NoMileageListing = 1 in this case, the second line where there is a case is the issue

Comment: I ask you, what type of `@NoMileageListing`? Because on the 1st line, it is such as table. But on the 2nd line, it is scalar variable. It may the problem.

Comment: I still have no clue what you mean, it's not a table, it's a variable from the start.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is located in the when part.
It should be:

```
SELECT CASE @NoMileageListing
WHEN @NoMileageListing = 1 THEN 'tblcargarage.miles >= 0'
ELSE 'tblcargarage.miles != 0'
END
INTO @NoMileWhereClause;
select @NoMileWhereClause;
```

to create the dynamic query with the @noMileWhereClause refer to the answer here:
[How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)